Add testers in new Google Home Developer Console
I have an own Google Home Action, which now was migrated to the "Google Home Developer Console". There I can't find any option to add testers anymore. Before in the old system, there was an extra menu in the deploy tab, where you can add alpha or beta testers.
It seems to be still possible, if you have the link to the old alpha test settings, if it already was activated. Still not the perfect solution, but if anyone needs the link, because you can't get there anymore: https://console.actions.google.com/project/<project_id>/release/userGroups/alpha
